# pass parameter and model from ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using ajax for the request I am passing a parameter `key` and a model to controller method but I can get the key on the method but getting the model value is always null when I am setting the `traditional` value true and 0 when I am sending it without traditional.

Here is my ajax method.

```js
 $('.search-hot-destination').on('click', '.rightdesti-list > a', function () {
            var key =  $(this).parents('li').find('.countryNameList').attr('id');
            var model ={
                DestinationCityID: $(this).attr('id')
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/destination",
                data: {key: key, model:model},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('hello');
                }
            })
        });
```

Here is my controller method.

```
      public ActionResult destination(string key, FilterDataViewModel model, string searchingkey, int skip = 0)
    {

    }
```

Here is my Model.

```
  public class FilterDataViewModel
    {
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public string SearchingKey { get; set; }
        public int DestinationCityID { get; set; }
        public int citykey { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` (you are not stringifying the data) and its just `data: {key: key, DestinationCityID: $(this).attr('id') },`

Comment: I have a question. If you are using a `ViewModel` why all the properties are not included in it? I mean (`key, searchingkey and skip`)?

Comment: Thanks you so much its working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax request you should `JSON.stringify(Object);`

```
data: JSON.stringify({key: key, model:model}),
```